# how to edit the layers in omnet++ or inet?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I want to create or edit the nodes in inet or omnet++.

Instead of having seven layers for example, I want a host with three layers (phys, mac and app)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl55f.png)

Comment: Does [OMNet++ documentation](https://omnetpp.org/documentation/) or [INET documentation](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/) help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: This is a valid question (that could have been answered with some research in the codebase)

Comment: @Eljay Yes the  documentations help so much, but I am really new and I feel that I am lost, and sometimes I don’t know how to combine the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches, from the most complex to the simplest:

- Build your own node from scratch (you can use `EthernetHost` as an example)
- Build your own host module but extend `LinkLayerNodeBase`. That will inherit only up to the link layer.
- Just use StandardHost and disable the layers you don't need (i.e. set the parameter `hasIpv4`, `hasUdp` and `hasTcp` to false)
- Just use StandardHost and ignore the unused layers. If an application opens a raw socket on layer 2 (like `EthernetApp` and all its descendant) then packets sent by the app will anyway directly sent to the linklayer and routed around the transport and network layers).